# For iOS, issue "talking" to frame and bounds elements of UIView and decendents

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview

Greetings all -

I am having an issue assigning a value to an existing UIScrollView. In response to an Orientation change, I am re-orienting and sizing the ScrollView and the UIImageViews I have contained within. I can set the UIScrollView's frame:

`CGRect wideThumbFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 530.0, 1024, 190.0);
        thumbScrollView.frame = wideThumbFrame;`

But I can't seem to adjust ONLY the bounds:

```
[thumbScrollView bounds].size.height = 190.0;
```

Compiler says "LValue required as left operand of assignment". Is not thumbScrollView my LValue?!?!? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, since bounds is a property, you have to assign it, to a local variable first, ie

```
CGRect rect = thumbScrollView.frame;
rect.size.height = 190.0;
thumbScrollView.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score 0):

...bounds.size.height is part of a CGRect structure.
You should assign it just like you do with the .frame CGRect structure property.
You can adjust the size by assigning a CGRect to the bounds property.

```
thumbScrollView.bounds = CGRectMake(thumbScrollView.bounds.origin.x, thumbScrollView.bounds.origin.y, thumbScrollView.bounds.size.width, 190.0);
```